# Running Matlab tasks on remote machine

Tags: linux, matlab, ssh, remote-desktop

I am working on machine learning task in Matlab (using Neural networks toolbox of Matlab). Thus I need to run computations that are very demanding in terms of RAM and processor time. My computer is not sufficient for that task but I have an access to Linux server that is powerful enough.

I am looking for the way how to run computational tasks from Matlab GUI that is running on my own computer on that server. Ideally it should work given these condition:

- My computer is running Windows 7, the server Red Hat Linux
- I can connect to the server only using SSH protocol (currently I'm using putty for that task)
- The server does not have Matlab installed. I can ask server admin to install it but that may take some time, it would be better if that is not needed. There is Java virtual machine (and development kit) installed on the server.
- I prefer to use Matlab GUI on my computer (not Matlab command line)

How can I do that? If you need more information about the settings or if you know other solutions please leave a comment. I'll be happy to respond.

Comment: (1) Install matlab on the server. (2) Install and run a VNC server on the server. (3) Install and run a VNC client on your machine. Then the server exports its desktop to your machine and you can use it like you sit directly in front of it, and this includes, of course, matlab.

Comment: @angainor I do not think so. Questions about how to set up programming environments are normally accepted here. This is no different. And I doubt that I would get much help on supper user or elsewhere.

Comment: @H.Muster Server admin will not allow VNC so that is not an option - unfortunately.

Comment: By the way, if you do not need the Matlab GUI, you can also run matlab via putty.

Comment: @H.Muster I don't know xming. What port does xming use for communication with the server?

Comment: You can write the code using gui on your computer, scp the code using SSH to the server and run there from the console. Programing using the GUI over the network is a bit clumsy for my taste.

Comment: If you do not want to install MATLAB there you can compile the code using `mcc`, deploy it on the server (you still need the matlab runtime installed there, but that you can do yourself, without the help of administrator)

Comment: Xming uses SSH. http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Comment: @angainor You last comment seems to be promising to me. Can you provide it as an answer with more detail on the process? I have never done something like that before so I could use some guidelines. It might very well become accepted answer for this problem.

Comment: @H.Muster Xming looks good as well. I will give it a try. Hope it works with the server...

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have matlab on the server, the only way is to:

> - modify the code such that it outputs a file
> - compile your code using `mcc` (toolbox required)
> - send it to your server (do you have a shared disk?, otherwise use `pscp` [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) )
> - execute it (using putty from command line)
> - get back the output file (same than sending)

We are all doing that in my lab (except that we are on ubuntu)

Comment: +1 Looks like this is the same procedure that was suggested by @angainor in his comments. It looks like it might be a little bit tedious it I needed to debug a code many often or run multiple experiments... But it is a way to do it. In case it takes a lot of time I'll ask admin to install Matlab (is there better way with Matlab installed on the server?).

Comment: @drasto Oli suggested similar thing as me. This method however is no good for development, only for production runs. So you have to write and prepare the code on your local desktop. In any case, have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/compiler/working-with-the-mcr.html) to know how to work with the Matlab Compiler Runtime.

Comment: @drasto, if you have matlab installed on server, and the parallel toolbox, you can use it to work remotely seamlessly. I have never done it, but I know that it is possible.  https://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/index.html;jsessionid=ff297a60d129baafa3f5c1906146

Comment: That would be ideal. But is parallel toolbox operating system independent? Otherwise there could be problem because my computer is running Windows and server Linux.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted at in the comments, [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/) + [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/) could address this, and if you're actively updating the code, it may be simpler than the `mcc` approach. However, you do have to install the MDCS piece on the server and get things set up. If you're not using any MEX files, the difference in architecture should be irrelevant. If you are using MEX files, you need to ensure that you can compile them for the server architecture and make them available there.

Comment: Some time has passed and the admins have finally installed Matlab on that machine. Right now I'm working like this: I connect to server as to remote desktop (using putty, display forwarding and Xming X server for Windows). This way I'm able to work with server resources in Matlab in GUI mode. But the GUI is **very** slow. So the better way would be to use parallel toolbox. The information I have found on how to use it are little confusing to me. Can you provide some more info on how to make the setup work? Do I need to install MDCS at all? If so can I install it on my desktop computer?

Comment: You need to install Parallel Computing Toolbox on your desktop machine, and MDCS on the cluster machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can run MATLAB jobs on remote Linux server from your local PC without the MDCS setup however for large scale and multiple users the MCDS is highly recommended. You can use plink to automated the putty command line execution from MATLAB.

We are executing our Simulink model simulations with multiple iterations on a more capable remote Linux server. You will require the following:

1) MATLAB installation on both client and server machine with  parallel computing toolbox

2) Mapped Linux server shared network drive (for data I/O)

3) Plink for automated Putty

4) Command line script for silent MATLAB execution on the remote machine

MATLAB code example:

```
plinkFile = which('plink.exe');

command = [plinkFile ' -ssh ' [ServerUrl] ' -l ' [Username] ...
                    ' -pw ' [Password] ' matlab -nodesktop -nosplash ' ...
                    '-r "' [RemoteScriptName] ...
                    '\(\''' InputDataSharedDriveFilePath] '\''\);" &'];  

[status,cmdout] = system(command);
```